# Does a lady have a Chiuv to eat on Erev Yom Kippur?

Tags: yom-kippur, food, women

Does a lady have a Chiuv to eat on Erev Yom Kippur? The Shaagas Aryeh questions from one side it is a Mitzvas Asei Shehazman Grama and they should be Pottur. However they have a Chiuv to fast on Yom Kippur and maybe if you have to fast you also have to eat the day prior? The Shaagas Aryeh leaves it as a Tzoruch Iyun.

Comment: Is eating on EY"K a Mitzva, per se?

Comment: So yodeyans are supposed to know more than the Shaagas Aryeh?

Comment: Isaac, the question is if it's a separate mitzva it might be asey shehazman grama.  If it's connected to a lav somehow (like don't-eat-chametz,-do-eat-matza) then women are definitely obligated.

Comment: Gershon - it sounds like you've already answered your question. Do you mean to ask whether later poskim take a stand on the S.A.'s tzorich iyyun?

Comment: Dave - that is what I want to know - Are there any other Poskim discussing this and how did they rule?

Comment: It is a Mitzva Asai to eat on Erev Yom Kippur. That is the reason we have a Seudas Mitzva on Erev Yom Kippur.

Comment: Perhaps, then, you should edit your question to reflect what you really mean to ask.

Comment: Rabbi Akivah Eiger in _Tshuvos_ asks the same question. He explains that the reason why here it should not be a _Zman Grama_ is because the way _Chazal_ learn out that it is a _Mitzvah_ to eat on _Erev Yom Kippur_ is from the _posuk "Me'tisha Ba'erev"_ which is talking about fasting. So maybe the _mitzvah_ to eat on _EY"K_ is like fasting which is a _Lav_.

Answer (score 1):

By *Hilchos Tefilah*, Tosafos are quoted in the famous controversy regarding whether women are obligated to daven. They say that the rule that women are from a time-bound, positive commandment only applies to *mitzvos di'oraisa* (commandments that the Torah itself directs us to do). Regarding Rabbinic Mitzvos this rule does not necessarily apply.

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying.

Comment: Gershon, sorry! I have been out of Lakewood so long that I forgot to write in that language: Mir zein fun Shitas Tosafos in Brachos bai di inyan fun nashim chayavos bi'tefilah az nashim ken zayn are chayavos in ah diRabanandige mitzvas asei shehazman gramah. Essing on erev Yom Kippur is midirabanan. Az lefi Tosafos di tzarich iyun fun di Shaages Aryeh is nit azei sh'ver.

Comment: What controversy is there if women are obligated to daven? Everyone agrees they are. It's an explicit Mishna.

Answer (score 1):

Hacham Yishak Yosef in Yalkut Yosef Moadim Page 74 (or Siman 604, Seif 6 in the Kisur version), says that women are obligated to eat Erev Yom Kippur, because the Pasuk brings the commandment in the form of a negative commandment, i.e. Veinitem.

Answer (score -1):

I found that the Ksav Sofer says that women do have a Chiyuv to eat on Erev Yom Kippur.

Comment: Where??????????